# Read CSV file based on columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working in an Angular js project where I have to read the CSV file column wise using javascript. I have retrieved the CSV and printed it in the console. I am able to split the csv row wise. How to do it based on columns?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same way but with your specific column-delimiter?

Comment: Why not use [this](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/)?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi I'm not sure trying to use jq libraries in angularjs is a good idea

Comment: don't use it for `DOM handling`, instead only get your CSV converted to `JS object`.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is nothing but a 2 dim array. By using 2 for loop you can do.

for example:

```
  for(var i=0;i<col.length;i++){
   for(var j=0;j<rows.length;j++){
      arr[i][j]
   }
 }
```

Comment: Since he mentions splitting the CSV, I don't think he already has an array but rather the text content of the CSV.

Comment: @Aaron  I have retrieved the CSV and printed it in the console. I am able to split the csv row wise.he already mentioned

Comment: I'm not sure I understood ; in your answer you're not splitting, you're indexing. He said he was able to split in rows, so I assumed he did something like that : `myCSVtextInput.split("\n")` which gives an array of rows. From there I think he should probably obtain the cells by splitting around his specific column-delimiter to obtain the 2 dimensional array you mention

Comment: @ankitgupta I dont have an array .

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, it sounds easy to parse CSV files but it can get complicated quickly (depending on where your CSV comes from: user-generated, fixed in format from an API, ...):

- Parsing headers
- Different number of headers and data columns
- Delimiter (Germans often use `;` instead of `,`)
- Number format (Germans often use the `,` instead of `.` as decimal separators)
- Quoted data (maybe with a delimiter inside the quote data)
- Whitespace
- Line endings
- ...

That's why there are a lot of CSV parsers available on npm (https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=csv). Some are focused on parsing speed (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv) some on convenience (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse).

But all have in common (as far as I know) that they return row wise. Which is often caused to be able to process streams which will pass the data line wise and not column wise.

Here's a code example to get your data column wise:

```
const input = `header_1,header_2
value 1,value 2
value 3,value 4`

// get rows -> here \n as line ending is known
const rows = input.split('\n');

// get the first row as header
const header = rows.shift();

// get number of columns by splitting the header
// , as delimiter is known here. Could be different ...
const numberOfColumns = header.split(',').length

// initialize 2D-array with a fixed size
const columnData = [...Array(numberOfColumns)].map(item => new Array());

for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
  var row = rows[i];
  var rowData = row.split(',');

  // assuming that there's always the same
  // number of columns in data rows as in header row
  for(var j=0; j<numberOfColumns; j++) {
    columnData[j].push(rowData[j]);
  }
}

console.log("columnData = " + JSON.stringify(columnData, null, 4));
```

Output will be:

```
columnData = [
    [
        "value 1",
        "value 3"
    ],
    [
        "value 2",
        "value 4"
    ]
]
```

Not included is stripping whitespace, converting numbers, ...

For convinience you could use `papaparse` to get the data row wise and use the nested `for` loop again:

```
const Papa = require('papaparse');

// example data with delimiter ; and empty lines
const input = `header_1;header_2
1;"2"

3;4`;

// options for papaparse
const parseOptions = {
    quoteChar: '"', // quoting character
    delimiter: ';',
    skipEmptyLines: true, // ignore empty lines
    dynamicTyping: true,  // parse numbers automatically
}

const parseResult = Papa.parse(input, parseOptions);
const parsedData = parseResult.data;

// get the first row as header
const header = parsedData.shift();

const numberOfColumns = header.length;

// initialize 2D-array with a fixed size
const columnData = [...Array(numberOfColumns)].map(item => new Array());

for(var i=0; i<parsedData.length; i++) {
  var rowData = parsedData[i];

  for(var j=0; j<numberOfColumns; j++) {
    columnData[j].push(rowData[j]);
  }
}

console.log("columnData = " + JSON.stringify(columnData, null, 4));
```

Output will be:

```
columnData = [
    [
        1,
        3
    ],
    [
        2,
        4
    ]
]
```